# Solve equation Matlab

Tags: matlab, bessel-functions

Hy can anyone can tell me how i can solve this equation 
2xJ1(x) − J0(x) = 0
where J1 and J0  are the Bessel function
in Matlab without using the fsolve command

Comment: Are you asking about using numerical methods to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fzero` to find the zeros *if and only if* the curve crosses the x-axis. So

```
fzero(@(x)(2*x*besselj(1,x)-besselj(0,x)),x0)
```

will give you the zero close to `x0`.

See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846939/difference-between-fzero-and-fsolve-for-one-variable/5847286#5847286) for an explanation of when and why `fzero` fails (although it won't for a Bessel function, it's good to be aware) and the tradeoffs with `fsolve`.